# Will wrong or incomplete Microdata harm my SEO?

Tags: seo, microdata

What if I am missing parts of my Microdata?

I will use a blog article for example. The recommended markup is:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <span itemprop="name">How to Tie a Reef Knot</span>
  by <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
  This article has been tweeted 1203 times and contains 78 user comments.
  <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserTweets:1203"/>
  <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserComments:78"/>
</div>
```

Now let’s say that I quickly want to switch this article to be a recipe, but I don’t add additional tags (like here http://prntscr.com/38fwyk) and only change the `itemtype`:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
  <span itemprop="name">Burgers</span>
  by <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
  This article has been tweeted 1203 times and contains 78 user comments.
  <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserTweets:1203"/>
  <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserComments:78"/>
</div>
```

Would this actually harm my SEO?

Comment: I don't think it would hurt it. Just any benefit the microformat offered would not be available to you.

Comment: Thank you bud. This is to become a part of Joomla 3.3 so I am asking around to find out if there will be some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if all you did was change the schema type, the markup would most likely be incomplete, so it would not benefit you much at all.  The other issue is if the itemtype is incorrect and/or inappropriate, Google might view the markup as being somewhat deceitful and may disable all rich snippets for the site.

Comment: Oups! You sure about that ? The disabling rich snippets for entire site ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that.  They will take manual action if they feel that a site is trying to manipulate the structured data in order to obtain rich snippets in the SERPs.  And yes, it will affect the entire site, not just certain pages.